# What is the usage of Debug -> Start external program in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have created two solutions in Visual Studio 2017:

- first one with console application `Example1`
- second one with class library `ClassLibrary1`

ClassLibrary1 contains only one file `MyLib.cs`:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class MyLib
    {
        public string Foo()
        {
            return "Bla";
        }
    }
}
```

In first solution (the one with Example1 console application) I added **existing project -> ClassLibrary1**.

I configured ClassLibrary1 as a Startup project and set Debug -> Start external program as shown in the picture:

[image]

So now you just start the project (in my case ClassLibrary1) and the Debug works (I set breakpoint in the return "Bla";). What happens is that Example1.exe calls ClassLibrary.MyLib file.

Have I understood the `Debug -> Start external program` correctly usage or is there any other usage?

Comment: You use this when the program you need to execute is not the one you're developing. It could be that you're developing a plugin, or it is written in a programming language that Visual Studio doesn't support, like Delphi, or something similar to that.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen so for example that Delphi calls your DLL and then you can debug your DLL in Visual Studio.

Comment: @broadband You could also just have your dll project open and start the other application and then click in visual studio `Debug\Attach to process` and select the running application and put a breakpoint in you code and it will break in when the method is called.

Comment: @broadband Exactly, we do this at work, we have a Delphi application that we also develop, and lots of .NET code that the Delphi application loads by hosting the .NET runtime. By configuring Visual Studio to start the Delphi-produced .exe file, we can set breakpoints and debug the .NET code normally. We cannot debug into the Delphi code from Visual Studio but we can always switch to the Delphi IDE for that part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You normally use it if you have something external starting up your code. Like, if you are developing a DLL, and some other process outside your project starts it up.

For example you could be developing a plugin `ThingyPlugin` for `Thingy.exe`. Then you would specify `Thingy.exe` here as a means to get your plugin loaded.

If you don't have an external process, you might as well use `Start Project`.

Answer (score 4):

> Have I understood the Debug -> Start external program correctly usage or is there any other usage?

No. Usually you would use *Start Project*, unless you have an external program that needs to be started in order to debug your project.

I have used this myself in quite some cases, primarily when developing add-ins for other software, like a class library that is actually a plugin for Autodesk Revit, unsupported Microsoft Office versions, etc.

Comment: Yes, Revit and Solidworks add ins are good examples. I use them alot. They load at startup and you can't debug the software itself. you have to attach to process or set the external program command

Comment: @Franck so Attaching to existing process is the same as Setting external program. The only difference is that Visual Studio starts the program when set external program is used

Comment: @broadband the difference is that the start external will launch lets say the EXE that use the dll and then will find the process and attach to it automatically. If you press stop it should stop the EXE (some unstable programs are picky and won't close but that's not the point). If you do need to run lets say 3 times the EXE that use your DLL you will need to attach to one of them you are interested into debugging and when you want to switch you detach and attach to another. This does NOT stop the application from running. So that would be the main points of both mode.